# SQL "UPDATE" Gives an error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have made a simple blog system, in procedural PHP, where the user can make new post's, see existing posts, so it's a CRUD system.

So this is my code here:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $titel = $_POST['titel'];
  $kortbeskrivelse = $_POST['kortbeskrivelse'];
  $skrib = $_POST['skrib'];
  $post = $_POST['post'];

  $update = "UPDATE posts SET ";
  $update .= "title = '{$titel}', ";
  $update .= "kortbe = '{$korbeskrivelse}', ";
  $update .= "author = '{$skrib}', ";
  $update .= "beskrivelse = '{$post}', ";
  $update .= "WHERE id=$pid LIMIT 1";

  $updateresult = mysqli_query($conn, $update);

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $updateresult)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $updateresult . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
} 

}
```

So to explain the query, i'm updating posts, with the variables passed from a POST form.

The $pid variable, is for ensure that it's updating the correct post (I have declared it before the sql query)

I'm not getting any PHP errors, and the connection works great. 
This is the SQL error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id= LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

So it's a little bit confusing, and i am afraid it's an error 40(Human error :D )

I know it's very insecure, it's also for demonstrating injections etc.

I hope someone can help me out!

Thank's in advance!

Comment: add your form code as well

Comment: Apparently `$pid` results in an empty string.

Comment: Please read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Your code is vulnerable.

Comment: Sticky bit, please read the post :-D

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma in this line `$update .= "beskrivelse = '{$post}', ";`. Try removing it:

```
$update .= "beskrivelse = '{$post}' ";
```

Comment: can we '{}' in our query

Comment: yes, try reading up here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: that wasn't it.. But now it just says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: than that was it. this one is another error.. try `print $update; exit();` before the `mysqli_query` and show us the output.

Comment: Hmm wierd.. now it says UPDATE posts SET title = 'a', kortbe = '', author = 'a', beskrivelse = 'a' WHERE id= LIMIT 1 - looks like it isn't getting the kortbe, or id.

Comment: yes, it looks like `$pid` is not defined. You have it in `$_POST` too?

Comment: you can add the `$pid` variable to your form as a hidden input (for example `<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="$pid">`), and then after the if here, use `$pid = $_POST['pid']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$update = "UPDATE posts SET ";
$update .= "title = '$titel', ";
$update .= "kortbe = '$korbeskrivelse', ";
$update .= "author = '$skrib', ";
$update .= "beskrivelse = '$_POST[beskrivelse]' ";
$update .= "WHERE id=$pid LIMIT 1";
```

change your code like this don't use {} brackets in query and remove ',' from last $update and put some value in '$pid'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$update .= "WHERE id={$pid} LIMIT 1";`

The text format with $ pid does not return the "PID" value but the text '$pid'.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

> your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id= LIMIT 1' at line 1

Look closer and you'll notice `id=`. There is no rvalue for the `=` operation. For some reason your `$pid` is empty. The code snippet doesn't show where `$pid` comes from.

Apart from that you also have a comma after the last column.

```
$update = "UPDATE posts SET ";
$update .= "title = '{$titel}', ";
$update .= "kortbe = '{$korbeskrivelse}', ";
$update .= "author = '{$skrib}', ";
$update .= "beskrivelse = '{$post}' "; // removed comma
$update .= "WHERE id=$pid LIMIT 1";
```

Also, the way you're building the query, your application is vulnerable. Read about ["SQL Injection"](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and fix your code to use parametrized queries instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, and please, read the post :D It's meant to be vulnerable.